# Put css into head but css is part of an imported file

Tags: php, html, css

Webpagetest.org tells me that

```
http://mypage.com/howitworks has CSS in the document body:
Link node http://mypage.com/design_header.css should be moved to the document head.
```

This design_header.css is the stylesheet of header.php which is imported in the body e.g.

```
<body>
 <?php include 'header_login.php'; ?>
</body>
```

Is there something I can do about this?

Comment: if you inspect the contents of `header_login.php` it would not have the `<head>` tag. There is no harm in importing the `css` file to the `head` section of the webpage

Comment: The content of that php file is certainly have a `<head>` tag with the stylesheet.

Comment: oh.. then you have a problem, because you have a `head` within a `body`

Comment: That's right because I am importing a php file in the body.

Comment: Remove the `<head>` tags from the import file as `<head>` do not belong within the `<body>` of a html document. Why would you include `<head>` tags within the `<body>` of a HTML document!? Nex thing would be to remove the CSS `<style>` from the include file and into the `<head>` of the HTML document, when i say `<head>` i mean the correct one, not the one that's aimlessly floating around in the mashed together include file. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might tell you that you need a decent PHP Templating System for your views ([Smarty](http://www.smarty.net)?).

But, if you're looking for a quick solution, try to leverage `Output Buffering` for your needs:

```
<?php
// at the top of your parent page

function move_css_to_head($buffer)
{
    // do some DOM manipulation here to achieve your goal
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($buffer);

    $head = $dom->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0);
    $body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
    $css_elms = $body->getElementsByTagName('link');

    foreach ($css_elms as $elm)
        {
        $head->appendChild($elm->cloneNode());
        $body->removeChild($elm);
        }

    return $dom->saveHTML();
}

ob_start('move_css_to_head'); // buffer response output, and call the assigned function upon flushing
?>

<!-- Regular Page Content -->

<?php
// at the bottom of your parent page, flush the buffer
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: I didn't check `move_css_to_head` function, first make sure it doesn't cause any error.

Comment: For a start, comment all of the function lines, add `return $buffer` instead, and see if it works.

Comment: How and where do I call the function?

Comment: Add this lines to the top of your page:  `ini_set('display_errors', '1'); ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Nothing. Do I have to call the function somewhere?

Comment: I had some errors in the `move_css_to_head` function, try the revised one now.

Comment: Another revision, please try now

Comment: I moved the function to the top of the page, before calling `ob_start`, try now.

Comment: No change. Still a blank page. After your code adding an `echo 'a'` is not displayed, but it is when I remove your code.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `ob_end_flush` at the end?

Comment: Positive. Right after the `</html>` tag.

Comment: Well, i finally realized i have to check the code in my `localhost` instead of blindly coding. it does work for me now. please use the last revision.

Comment: It throws some errors but it does without your function as well thanks to the error reporting. Can we continue tomorrow? It's really late here. Btw the first error is `require_once($_SERVER['SERVER_ROOT'].'dbconset.php');` - undefined index: SERVER_ROOT. I am using free webhosting now if that matters.

Comment: The first error you mention is not related to the changes you made. please note that i made another one last change in the function. we can continue tomorrow, i'll look for the message.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error' in /home/aXXXXXXX/public_html/howitworks3.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /home/aXXXXXXX/public_html/howitworks3.php(17): DOMNode->removeChild(Object(DOMElement)) #1 /home/aXXXXXXX/public_html/howitworks3.php(299): move_css_to_head('?<!DOCTYPE html...', 5) #2 {main} thrown in /home/aXXXXXXX/public_html/howitworks3.php on line 17 (`  $body->removeChild($elm);`)

Comment: I receive this error if I remove the ini_set and error_reporting lines. If I don't remove them I get non-relevant errors and only the header is displayed. After removal I see the whole webpage then the errors.

Comment: The structure of your DOM is apparently confusing the DOM parser, please post the full HTML output of your page.